# How to turn off Tomcat logging in Eclipse?

Tags: tomcat, logging, tomcat6, eclipse

I develop a Vaadin project in Eclipse that I start through Tomcat 6 which gets started directly by Eclipse. Tomcat prints an enormous amount of log messages though on each start which makes it hard to see the output of my own Application. I have already replaced all log levels in `tomcat6/conf/logging.properties` by `WARNING` (e.g. `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = WARNING`) but I still get many `INFO` messages.
How can I turn this off or restrict the log messages to `WARNING`?

**An example of the messages**

```
Okt 26, 2012 12:16:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.24.
Okt 26, 2012 12:16:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Okt 26, 2012 12:16:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:saim' did not find a matching property.
Okt 26, 2012 12:16:37 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Okt 26, 2012 12:16:37 PM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
Okt 26, 2012 12:16:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 879 ms
Okt 26, 2012 12:16:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Okt 26, 2012 12:16:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.32
Okt 26, 2012 12:16:37 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Okt 26, 2012 12:16:37 PM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
Okt 26, 2012 12:16:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 568 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out ${catalina.base}/conf/logging.properties.  This is where the logging levels for tomcat are set.

You probably want to crank it up to **`WARN`** from **`INFO`** / **`FINE`**.

More info: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html

Comment: You might also consider adding custom logging to your application so it goes to a separate file.

Comment: But that's exactly what I wrote: "I have already replaced all log levels in tomcat6/conf/logging.properties by WARNING".

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that.  Sorry.  Have you considered adding a custom log for your application?

Comment: I am using this approach: https://www.kubos.cz/2019/07/05/no-startup-logs-tomcat-Eclipse. What you are missing is passing path to the logging.properties. You can fix it that by adding -Djava.util.logging.config.file=path/logging.properties into Run configurations->Arguments->VM arguments.